# how to mark the minimum of a function in a certain range?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the MWE below,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=101, blue]{(1.5*x)^((x/(1-x)))};
\addplot [domain=-10:10, samples=101, red]{(10*x)^((x/(1-x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I tried to follow the advice from cmhughes

[Pgfplots : can't plot some usual mathematical functions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/pgfplots-cant-plot-some-usual-mathematical-functions)

How could I plut the two functions zoomed in the range x \in (0,1)

What is it that is wrong in my example, please?
Also can I somehow indicate the minima or something like a dashed line from the x axis to the minimum point of the curve?

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed @Jake. Could you please have a small look at the modified question?

Comment: Yes @Jake I had got that part, but as you see the scale of y axis is huge. How could I zoom to focus on (0,1) range?

Comment: Could you please edit the question title to more accurately reflect what you're asking? Also, please ask only one question per post, the question about the minima should go in its own post (please also search this site for answers before asking, there have been similar questions before).

Comment: @Jake: Indeed, I totally agree and did as you suggested. Yes I am trying to find the relevant question...any advice on how to search better and faster will be appreciated. Cheers