# Why can't I plot (x+2)^{1/3} properly using pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm using the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=5,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        samples=100,
        domain=-5:5,
    ]
        \addplot[thick](x,{(x+2)^(1/3)});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

to plot `y= (x+2)^{1/3}` which gives me this graph:
[image]

but it is not complete, because the right graph is:

[image]

**How can I plot it like the second screenshot?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: [PGF Math Function to compute cube root](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root) or [Pgfplots : can't plot some usual mathematical functions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/pgfplots-cant-plot-some-usual-mathematical-functions/69531#69531).

Comment: f(x) is not real for x<2, because (x+2)^(1/3)=exp(1/3*ln(x+2)) and ln(x) is only defined for x>0. You'll get the complete graph (on the real part) with `domain=-2:5`.

Comment: You might also want to check [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B2%29^%281%2F3%29).

Comment: @djp: Thanks for your links, but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: From the code given in the second link, modify to (x+2)/abs(x+2)*abs(x+2)^(1/3) and the graph gets shifted as you asked.

Comment: @anderstood: here we have 3 which is an odd number. Why the domain of `(x+2)^(1/3)` is `[-2,\infty)`?

Comment: Well, f can be defined from R to R. For any real, the cube root is either a real or two conjugate complex numbers. You can do as suggested by DJP, but the reason why `pgfplot` does not work is, _I guess_, because it uses the definition x^p=exp(p*ln(x)). Maybe someone can confirm or not that pgfplots works this way. Anyway, that's probably not a coincidence that the graph started at x=2.