# How to draw graph of logarithm function?

Tags: graphs

I can draw polynomials using Tikz in Latex but I am not able to draw graphs of logarithms,exponential etc.

Comment: have a look at, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/pgfplots-cant-plot-some-usual-mathematical-functions and lots and lots of the other `pgfplots` questions

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try some thing like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[restrict y to domain=-10:10]
\addplot [blue,domain=-10:10, samples=200]{log10(x)};
\addplot [red, domain=-10:10, samples=200]{exp(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can refer to the [PGFPLOTS manual](http://ctan.asis.io/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf) for more plots.