# How to plot functions involving rational exponents using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

The power functions that i'm trying to plot isn't showing up fully, i've tried changing the domains and stuff but to no avail, can i get some help here please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmax = {4},
    xmin = {-1},
    ymax = {2},
    ymin = {-2},
    legend pos = outer north east
]
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
]
{x^(1/2)};
\addlegendentry{$y=\sqrt{x}$}
\addplot [
    domain=-5:5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{x^(1/4)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmax = {4},
    xmin = {-4},
    ymax = {2},
    ymin = {-2},
    legend pos = north west
]
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=black,
]
{x^(1/3)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$}
\addplot [
    domain=-10:10, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
]
{x^(1/5)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{5}}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make it compilable by adding document class and packages required.  Welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). As Jesse said, It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  I would recommend you use `(x)` instead of just `x`. Otherwise I get two graphs output.  Also, please clarify what you mean by "_showing up fully_".

Comment: My apologies, i've edited it accordingly. By not showing up fully, i mean that the graphs of y=x^(1/3) and y=x^(1/5) are not showing up at the 3rd quadrant as it is supposed to.

Comment: Try using `(x)` instead of `x` and [PGF Math Function to compute cube root](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root) may be of help.

Comment: changing to (x) doesn't help, what about the fifth root though? The cubic root function won't work on it.

Comment: The same logic can be employed to generate the 5th root.

Comment: seems like a duplicate of either http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278331/addplot-command-fails-to-generate-graph-for-function-with-rational-exponents/278333#278333, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144454/how-to-plot-x1-3, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/pgfplots-cant-plot-some-usual-mathematical-functions, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root,

Comment: @cmhughes: I suggested one of those to the OP, but it was not clear to the OP how to adapt a 5th root (as per the comments).

Comment: @PeterGrill fair enough. I'm still surprised that changing a '3' to a '5' needs a new question :) Happy to vote for you, nonetheless!

Comment: @cmhughes: Yes it is that simple, but that is _assuming_ one can read the code. I can actually relate to the OPs difficulties as it often takes me several guesses as to where to make slight changes to some of the  `expl3` solutions I am using. Similarly, when it comes to expansion issues. Also, there was a bizarre issue of the 2nd plot needing a `\hspace*{-23.5cm}` to be able to see it -- see the edit history. Jake rescued me on that one so no longer an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt the solution from [PGF Math Function to compute cube root](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root) to generate a function that computes the third and fifth root:

[image]

### References:

- [PGF Math Function to compute cube root](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRoot}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(#1)))/3)}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{FifthRoot}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(#1)))/5)}%
}


\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
     axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmax = {4},
    xmin = {-1},
    ymax = {2},
    ymin = {-2},
    legend pos = south east
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=orange,
    line width=1.0pt,
]
{(x)^(1/2)};
\addlegendentry{$y=\sqrt{x}$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:5, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue,
    line width=1.0pt,
]
{(x)^(1/4)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{4}}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\par
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xmax = 4,
    xmin = -4,
    ymax = 2,
    ymin = -2,
    legend pos = south east,
    clip=true,
]
\addplot [
    domain=-4:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=blue, 
    line width=1.0pt,
]
{CubeRoot(x)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$}
\addplot [
    domain=-4:4, 
    samples=100, 
    color=red,
    line width=1.0pt,
]
{FifthRoot(x)};
\addlegendentry{$y=x^{\frac{1}{5}}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Jake: Thanks. That was quite the space for a missing `%`. Whatever happened to multiple spaces are treated as a single space? :-)