# pgfplots not plotting all of the domain

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the function $-0.5x^{\frac{4}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}}+1.2x+1$ over the interval $[-2,5]$ but the graph for negative $x$ values is not plotting. How do I get the graph when $x$ is negative?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    xmin = -2.5, xmax = 4.5,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 2.5,
    xtick = {-2,-1.191,-0.103,0,0.292,1,2,4.144}]
    \addplot[
        domain = -5:5,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
    ] {-0.5*x^(4/3)-x^(1/3)+1.2*x+1};
\end{axis}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been raised before several times ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144454/how-to-plot-x1-3), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291727/how-to-plot-functions-involving-rational-exponents-using-pgfplots/291740#291740), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19052/pgf-math-function-to-compute-cube-root), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278331/addplot-command-fails-to-generate-graph-for-function-with-rational-exponents/278333#278333)). The problem seems to lie in the way PGF deals with roots and fractional powers using logarithmic functions. (For more details, see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69411/pgfplots-cant-plot-some-usual-mathematical-functions).)

As suggested by the author of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/47927), you can use the expression `x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)` to replace `x^(1/3)` in order to circumvent the above problem. You would then get:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    xmin = -2.5, xmax = 4.5,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 2.5,
    xtick = {-2,-1.191,-0.103,0,0.292,1,2,4.144},
    x post scale=2]
    \addplot[
        domain = -5:5,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
    ] {-0.5*x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(4/3)-x/abs(x)*abs(x)^(1/3)+1.2*x+1};
\end{axis}
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the left half might be wrong here.  I get a negative answer when I pass in -1.  This worked: ```\pgfmathdeclarefunction{CubeRoot}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(#1<0,-1,1)*exp((ln(abs(#1)))/3)}%
}```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    xmin = -2, xmax = 6,
    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 2.5,
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
    xtick = {-2,-1.191,-0.103,0,0.292,1,2,4.144},
    x post scale=4,
]
    \addplot[
        domain = -2:6,
        samples = 200,
        smooth,
        thick,
        blue,
    ] {-0.5*x^(4/3)-x^(1/3)+1.2*x+1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Very wide graph]

Comment: Nice!  But why is there no graph to the left of the $y$-axis?  The function is defined on all real numbers.

Comment: First or all, these are cube roots, not even-powered roots.  Second, don't speak to me that way.  I explicitly ask for the plot when $x$ is negative as well.

Comment: Asking me for the sqrt(-1) does not add to the question.